# How to redirect to another page in a new tab when i click on a menu in liferay?

Tags: liferay

I have added a couple of menu's in my portal. when I click on these menu's another page/url opens. My problem is that it opens in the same tab. When I click on the menu, the page must open in a new tab. How do I achieve this? 
I have another question too. How do i change the alignment of a portlet?I want the portlet in the left. Just dragging it to the left of the page, reduces its size. Maintaining, the full width, how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, so thought of posting it here.
To open in a new tab:

1. Click on Admin > Pages.
2. Select the respecctive page
3. In the side, there exists an option named "Advanced". Click on it
4. In the target field, enter **_blank**
5. Save

VOILA !!:D

For the alignment: change the css

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 questions, please find the answer.

1. Inorder to open page in new tab/windows use target="_blank" either through control panel advance options with page view settings or by updating theme's navigation.vm file.
2. For portlet layout, create new layout with 100% column width. Sample layout examples can be found in ROOT.war\layouttpl\custom path.